# Using inverse probability with conditional events

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

To reach Grenoble, France, from Turin, Italy, one can follow either of two routes. The first directly connects Turin and Grenoble, whereas the second passes through Chambery,France. During extreme weather conditions in winter, travel between Turin and Grenoble is notalways possible because some parts of the highway may not be open to traffic.

Denote with A, B,and C the events that highways from Turin to Grenoble, Turin to Chambery, and Chambery to Grenoble are open, respectively. In anticipation of driving from Turin to Grenoble, a traveler listens to the next days weather forecast. If snow is forecasted for the next day over the southern Alps, one can assume (on the basis of past records) that

Pr[A] = 0:6; Pr[B] = 0:7; Pr[C] = 0:4; Pr[C|B] = 0:5; and Pr[A|BC] = 0:4.

```
What is the probability that the traveler will be able to reach Grenoble from Turin?
What is the probability that the traveler will be able to drive from Turin to Grenoble by way of Chambery?
Which route should be taken in order to maximize his chance to reach Grenoble?
```

So for question one, should I calculate the inverse probability that all the roads are closed. What is the difference between the first and the second question?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Can you please explain in comment?

Comment: @DilipSarwate What I meant is that not being able to get to Gernoble is that all the roads are closed, with A or BC. So what you did is just calculating the second probability of BC.
My thought is having A' and (BC)', what do you think?